# Pandas find value corresponding to absolute minimum

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the actual value that corresponds to the absolute minimum from multiple columns. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, -5, -20, 50], 'B': [-5, 10, 30, 300], 'C': [15, 30, 15, 10]})
```

The output for this should be another another column with values -5, -5, 15 and 10.

I tried `df['D'] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].abs().min(axis=1)`, but it returns the minimum of absolutes, thereby losing the sign.

Comment: Where does the 10 come from?

Comment: `C` in the last row @ifly6 ?

Comment: If it's C, then where do the -5s come from? There's only three columns, so the min of the columns should give three answers. It can't be a min across, otherwise the 15 would be -20 instead.

Comment: Absolute minimum @ifly6 the minimum value not considering signs.

Comment: I see, that makes more sense, thanks! I was thinking that D was determined from min(A), min(B), and min(C) or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `idxmin`

```
df['D'] = df.values[df.index,df.columns.get_indexer(df[['A', 'B', 'C']].abs().idxmin(1))]
df
Out[176]: 
    A    B   C   D
0  10   -5  15  -5
1  -5   10  30  -5
2 -20   30  15  15
3  50  300  10  10
```

Comment: For row 2, the minimum should be -20, but this is giving 15. Could it be right?

Comment: Absolute minimum @MEdwin the minimum value not considering signs.

Comment: oh yes. You are right. I  missed the absolute.